# Get a Rocket chip to read instructions and execute them?

Tags: verilog, cpu, vivado, rocket-chip

After removing the reset from a Rocket chip, I would expect it to start reading instructions from memory, but this is not the case.

The ILA (Integrated Logic Analyzer) provided by Vivado does indicate that the AXI interface is *Inactive* and that no read commands are executed.

How can I get a Rocket chip to read instructions and execute them?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you check the address of the Reset Vector and the BootROM. If I remember correctly, all the rocket-chip cores are built to run from a bootrom out of the box. I believe the Zynq Configs are the same but I don't have experience using the Zynq configs. 
The design may be booting correctly at the wrong address so the processor will probably run garbage until a debug session is started.

If you want to boot from non-volatile memory then you will have to change this address. 
Hope this helps. 
Ciaran

Comment: regardless of the data that is in memory the rocket chip should at least try to read something, right?

so if i remove the reset the rocket chip should try to read from an address where the BootROM should be located.

Comment: Yes, this is true. If you are running in a simulator have you defined the simulation attributes?  I usually define these : +define+RANDOMIZE_REG_INIT
+define+RANDOMIZE_MEM_INIT
+define+RANDOMIZE

Comment: it is running on hardware. could it be that the front end server is needed to "activate" the cpu?

Comment: I doubt it, what I think is going on is, the riscv comes out off reset  and boots to an unknown location in memory. It would be worth simulating your design. See what location is accessed when you de-assert reset. Couple of follow up questions. 1) can you run a debug session on the riscv to run from an LSRAM r or DDR? 2)What's the memory map of the riscv? 3) what are you expecting the riscv to read? have you loaded a mem file somewhere? Hope this is helpful.

Comment: i am using an integrated logic analyzer to check what the cpu is doing. i would like to see if the cpu is at least able to send out an axi read request to get the first instruction. this is not happening. 1) setting up some simulation environment at the moment is not something i want to invest time in as i am currently evaluating different soft core CPUs regarding their ability to just send out a single axi read request. if the rocket chip is not able to read one single instruction i will not use it and therefore not waste any time with running simulations.

Comment: 2) no idea. 3) i don't care. i just want a life sign.

Comment: 1) i should clarify that i simulated the cpu with verilator but got no reaction from the cpu so i tried to run it on a fpga next. in previous answer to your first question i was talking about a more elaborate simulation setup.